# Swift protocol property check if weak

Tags: swift, xctest

Is it possible in XCTest to test a class property if it's weak or not.

```
class A {
  weak var p: String? = nil
}
```

**Result:** if p property of a class is weak then assert

Comment: See [Using unit tests to identify & avoid memory leaks in Swift](https://medium.com/@johnsundell/using-unit-tests-to-identify-avoid-memory-leaks-in-swift-607c97465b62)

Comment: Yes, this question is related to avoiding a retain cycle in a delegate pattern by using a unit testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an approach like this:

```
class TestObject {}

protocol A {
    var a: TestObject? { get set }
}

class B: A {
    var a: TestObject?
}

class C: A {
    weak var a: TestObject?
}

func addVar(to: A) {
    var target = to
    target.a = TestObject()  // Once we leave the scope of this function, the TestObject instance created here will be released unless retained by target
}

let b = B()
let c = C()

addVar(to: b)
addVar(to: c)

print(b.a)  // prints Optional(TestObject) because class C uses a strong var for a
print(c.a)  // prints nil because class B uses a weak var for a
```

Converted to a test case, it might look something like:

```
func testNotWeak() {

    func addVar(to: A) {
        var target = to
        target.a = TestObject()  // Once we leave the scope of this function, the TestObject instance created here will be released unless retained by target
    }

    let testClass = B()
    addVar(to: testClass)
    XCTAssertNotNil(testClass.a)
}
```